# Grant Admin Consent programmatically on newly created app registration

Tags: azure-active-directory

*TL;DR
To grant admin consent to a newly created single-tenant app I need to know its Service Principal Id. Is there a way of getting the Service Principal Id of a newly created app registration when it is not listed in the results from a call to the MS Graph API ServicePrincipals endpoint?*

I am using the Microsoft Graph Beta SDK to add functionality that enables users of our application to create and maintain SDS Sync Profiles.

I have a multi-tenant app registration which, given user consent, enables me to create a single-tenant app registration in the user's tenant using the `graphClient.Applications.Request().AddAsync({application})` method. The process I have works fine and the single-tenant app registration is created with the necessary permissions but these require admin consent. Currently I am sending users to the adminconsent endpoint: (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/adminconsent`) where the user can grant the necessary permissions. This is also working fine but it requires the user to log in again, having already logged in once to grant consent to the multi-tenant app. This is clearly not great from a UX point of view so I would like to avoid the necessity of the user having to log in again if possible.

I came across this post: https://winsmarts.com/how-to-grant-admin-consent-to-an-api-programmatically-e32f4a100e9d which explains how to grant the admin consent programmatically . This involves creating an oAuth2PermissionGrant object with the scopes listed that admin consent is required for.

The issue I have is that in order to add the oAuth2PermissionGrant I need to know the Service Principal Id of the single-tenant app registration just created. However, when I make a call to the Graph API to list the Service Principals (`graphClient.ServicePrincipals.Request().GetAsync()`) the single tenant app registration is not listed, so I have no way of getting the Service Principal Id and thus cannot create the oAuth2PermissionGrant.

Once I grant admin consent to the permissions on the single-tenant app registration, either manually in Azure AD or via the adminconsent endpoint, the single-tenant app registration shows in the results from the call to ServicePrincipals endpoint.

Additionally, if I haven't granted admin consent, and just make a call to any Graph endpoint, and, when (having logged in again) the grant permissions page is shown, I don't tick the "consent for my organization" box, the permissions remain (as expected) in "require admin consent" status, however the single-tenant app registration now shows amongst the Service Principals list.

Sorry for the long question but any advice would be most appreciated.
Thanks
David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when I make a call to the Graph API to list the Service Principals (graphClient.ServicePrincipals.Request().GetAsync()) the single tenant app registration is not listed, so I have no way of getting the Service Principal Id and thus cannot create the oAuth2PermissionGrant.

That's because a service principal is not created automatically when you create an application through the APIs or with PowerShell. Azure Portal creates it for you at the same time when using it for convenience, but the raw APIs don't do that. You need to create the service principal, the only mandatory parameter is the appId (your app id/client id) if I recall correctly. Here is the documentation page for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Once the service principal has been created, you should be able to create the oauth2PermissionGrant objects that grant the permissions you want for all users in your directory.

Comment: That's great. Thanks very much - I'll give that a go.